# WPF with PRISM: Resource of some types not found when running the app if other resources from other types are not includes

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I found an issue with resources in the App.xaml file of a Microsoft PRISM (Prism.Wpf 7.2 and Prism.Unity 7.2) WPF MVVM application (.NET Framework 4.7.2 or Dotnet Core 3.1). If `App.xaml` includes only certain types (don't now which exactly) like `BooleanToVisibilityConverter` as a resource:

```
<unity:PrismApplication x:Class="WPF_XAML_Resource_Test.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:unity="http://prismlibrary.com/">
    <Application.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    </Application.Resources>
```

The designer does not complain when including the resource with the given key:

```
<Button ... Visibility="{Binding DeleteButtonIsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}">
```

But when I run the application I get the error "Exception: Cannot find resource named 'BooleanToVisibilityConverter'. Resource names are case sensitive."

A hack is, to include some other type like `SolidColorBrush` in `App.xaml`:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Dummy" Color="Red"/>
```

Then the exception is not thrown.

Can someone explain why I get the exception when I not include the dummy `SolidColorBrush` resource?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue but your workaround didn't help me. I made the converter to static and used it as a StaticResource.

Here is the code:

```
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public static BoolToVisibilityConverter Instance { get; private set; }

    static BoolToVisibilityConverter()
    {
        Instance = new BoolToVisibilityConverter();
    }
    private BoolToVisibilityConverter() { }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<Border Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToggleButton}, Converter={x:Static converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter.Instance}}"/>
```

Of course previously I added converters namespace resolver to the ResourceDictionary:

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyAssemblyName.Converters"
```

I still couldn't figure out what was the problem only that the resource order is not interchangeable. In my case it was not the problem, because the very first item in my App.Xaml ResourceDictionary was the BoolToVisibilityConverter.